# Solving parametric linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the following system of equations using linear algebra:
$$
    x -2y +4z = a\\
    5x -y +z = b\\
    -x  +3y -z = w\\
$$
So how can I tell if the equation has infinite solutions? Or that there isn't even any solution? What steps do I need to do in order to solve this equation?

Comment: Reduce to echelon form. The right-hand side of those equations which end with zero left-hand side tell you that information. To have solutions that right-hand side must be zero. In the cases in which there are solutions, the existence of variables that are not pivots tells you if there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: did you want $y$ on both sides of the third equation?

Comment: @abel I changed it to $w$, it was a mistake.

Comment: do you know how to row reduce $\pmatrix{1&-2&4\\5&-1&1\\-1&3&-1}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following:
$$
\scriptsize\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&4&a\\5&-1&1&b\\-1&3&-1&w\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&4&a\\0&9&-19&b-5a\\0&1&3&w+a\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&4&a\\0&1&3&w+a\\0&9&-19&b-5a\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&4&a\\0&1&3&w+a\\0&0&-46&b-14a-9w\end{bmatrix}.
$$
There are no free variables and the system is consistent. What does this tell you?

Comment: Thanks! I did tried to solve it and did and reached pretty similar outcome. so it means that for a=0 or w+a=0 or b-14a-9w=0
there is no solution to this equation. and if there is a solution its a single solution. Am I right?

Comment: Ok Thanks!. there is only a single solution for this equation. I got it.

Comment: Glad it helped and kudos for finishing it off! :)

Comment: This system has a single solution whataver $a,b,w$ could be.